# Requirements for American citizen to enter Botswana for three months

Tags: visas, money, botswana

I am an American citizen and will soon be traveling to Botswana, where I'll be staying for three months with a church.  What are the entry requirements? Will I need proof of sufficient funds for my stay and, if so, how do I prove that?

I will be transiting in Johannesburg, South Africa.  Does this have any other requirements?

Comment: Hi Amanda! Welcome to Travel SE! We're a QA website, the idea is that we get questions that have a clear answer. You appear to have multiple questions. Normally we split those up so others have the same issues can find them easier. Also, I believe some of your questions have been answered before. And I also think the entry requirement for Botswana as a US citizen is simple: a visa. Do you wish to know what the visa requirements are?

Comment: Also, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/36405 for a great explanation of how to use bank statements as proof of funds.

Answer (score 6):

Botswana is open for tourists, you can visit with a valid passport up to 90 days total within a calendar year. Notice that leaving the country and coming back does not renew the 90 days period. 
There is no need for for sufficient funds proof as far as I experienced, for myself or for visitors.

Valid passport (Botswana and South Africa) must have:

- At least two empty pages (BW)
- At least six months of validity remaining (RSA)
- <s>No added pages to your passport (RSA)</s>

If you are traveling with minors (under 18), there are additional stipulations:

- Birth certificate
- If traveling with one parent, you need a letter from the other parent approving the trip, this must be sign by a notary
- Refer to [SA Department of Home Affaires website](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/immigration-services) for more details or updates

One more thing, before you arrive I do recommend to join [Smart Traveler Enrollment Program (STEP)](https://step.state.gov/step/) program and receive email and updates from the US Consulate in Gaborone

Sources:

- I am living in Botswana as a foreign resident
- [US Passport and International Travel - South Africa](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/south-africa.html)
- [US Passport and International Travel - Botswana](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/botswana.html)

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: I don't see the prohibition on additional pages in the source.

Comment: @phoog You are right. It something I heard, I will try and find a source for it, if I can't, I will update the answer, thanks.

Comment: I checked an old passport of mine that had additional pages and that I also used once to enter South Africa.  Unfortunately for this question, but fortunately perhaps for my trip, the pages were added roughly a year after the trip.

Comment: This email from the US embassy is the reason for my confusion, I will edit the post. Sorry for the wrong info. Thank you. > Beginning on 1 January 2016, U.S. passport bearers who require more visa pages must apply for a new, 52-page passport book. For information about fees and forms for passport renewals, please visit the U.S. Department of State’s travel website here: http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports.html.

Comment: Yeah that's not a South Africa thing, but the State Department no longer being willing to add extra pages to passports, presumably because it was actually a convenient service for travelers (ok, I'll grant they probably had a real reason, but it's still irritating).